# Gray area question: Software to add forum functionality to a website

Tags: discussion

A new community member *(welcome!)*, just posted a question in which they are seeking recommendations for software to integrate into their website to add forum functionality.

Here is their question:
[Looking for open source code library which can add forum functionality to a website](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/78049/looking-for-open-source-code-bases-which-can-add-forum-functionality)

This appears to be a gray area for our community.  They are not asking for a code-snippet.  They want a complete software routine to perform this function (like a library).  On the other hand, they are looking for source code, and not an executable.

I see this as a bit of a gray area.  It's on-topic as much as any software library (for which we have *many* QA's), but it's off-topic because it's uncompiled source code.  That said, you don't compile HTML/CSS/JavaScript in the typical sense of the word "compile" (technically, there are exceptions, but I'm focusing on the most common use), so such a library/package would not be delivered compiled.

I'm fine either way with considering it on-topic or off-topic.  I lean towards considering it on-topic and treating it like a request for any other software library.

What would our community prefer?

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out: SR is about "software meeting ***specific requirements***" – and not about "code bases to pick snippets from to build your own software". See e.g.

- [Can I ask for programming language resource recommendations here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185)
- [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185)

So as it stands currently, the question is off-topic. A hint how to make it on-topic can be found with [Questions to “get inspiration” for new software is on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2448/185): Ask for free, open-source software that does what you want (i.e. software meeting specific requirements). It then either turns out there's no need anymore to write your own as a perfect match was found – or, if not, all recommendations should be open-source (as requested), so that goal was reached as a "side-effect" without the question being off-topic.

**TL;DR:**

- asking for code bases to borrow from: off-topic
- asking for open-source apps/libraries: fully on-topic